# 2 Selector by jQuery in same page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, selector

I tried add 2 Selector by JQuery but it's not display the content, if I added just one it's work fine so could you please help me to fix this issue the following is codes

the idea of this script display the oil price (fuel & Diesel) 3 types of fuel and 1 of diesel
the first selector is display the prices by number then the second one display the charts of prices by month.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var selects = $('select');
  var values = '';
  selects.each(function() {
    values += '.' + $(this).val();
  });
  $(values).show();
  $('select').on('change', function(index, value) {
    if ($('#SelectOne').val() == 'Diesel') {
      $('#SelectTwo').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#SelectTwo').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    $('#results_container > div').hide();
    var values = '';
    selects.each(function() {
      values += '.' + $(this).val();
    });
    $(values).show();
  });
});

jQuery(function($) {
  var selects = $('select');
  var values = '';
  selects.each(function() {
    values += '.' + $(this).val();
  });
  $(values).show();
  $('select').on('change', function(index, value) {

    $('#results_chart > div').hide();
    var values = '';
    selects.each(function() {
      values += '.' + $(this).val();
    });
    $(values).show();
  });
});
```

```css
#results_container>div,
#results_chart>div {
  display: none;
}

.result {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.dif,
.difp {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: red;
}

.arrow {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  border: solid Red;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <div id="select_container">
    <select id="SelectOne">
      <option value="Fuel">Fuel</option>
      <option value="Diesel">Diesel</option>
    </select>

    <select id="SelectTwo">
      <option value="E-Plus-91">E-Plus 91</option>
      <option value="Special-95">Special 95</option>
      <option value="Super-98">Super 98</option>
    </select>

    <select id="SelectThree">
      <option value="Liter">Liter</option>
      <option value="Galon">Galon</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="results_container" class="result">
    <div class="Fuel E-Plus-91 Liter">3.22 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-0.62</span><span class="difp">-16.15%</span></div>
    <div class="Fuel Special-95 Liter">3.30 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-0.62</span><span class="difp">-15.82%</span></div>
    <div class="Fuel Super-98 Liter">3.41 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-0.62</span><span class="difp">-15.38%</span></div>
    <div class="Fuel E-Plus-91 Galon">12.24 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-2.36</span><span class="difp">-16.15%</span></div>
    <div class="Fuel Special-95 Galon">12.54 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-2.36</span><span class="difp">-15.82%</span></div>
    <div class="Fuel Super-98 Galon">12.96 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-2.36</span><span class="difp">-15.38%</span></div>
    <div class="Diesel Special-95 Super-98 E-Plus-91 Liter">3.87 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-0.27</span><span class="difp">-6.52%</span></div>
    <div class="Diesel Special-95 Super-98 E-Plus-91 Galon">14.71 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-1.03</span><span class="difp">-6.52%</span></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</center>

<center>
  <div id="select_chart">
    <select id="SelectOne1">
      <option value="cFuel">Fuel</option>
      <option value="cDiesel">Diesel</option>
    </select>

    <select id="SelectTwo1">
      <option value="cLiter">Liter</option>
      <option value="cGalon">Galon</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="results_chart" class="result">
    <div class="cFuel cLiter">[visualizer id="36" lazy="no" class=""]</div>
    <div class="cFuel cGalon">[visualizer id="39" lazy="no" class=""]</div>
    <div class="cDiesel cLiter">[visualizer id="43" lazy="no" class=""]</div>
    <div class="cDiesel cGalon">[visualizer id="48" lazy="no" class=""]</div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</center>
```

you can check it in my website oileprice.ae

I'm using Wordpress platform

Comment: limit each action to a narrow selector like ID.

Comment: TBH it's unclear what the issue is or what you're trying to do.   "I tried to add 2 selector" "it didn't work" "fix it for me".  The code doesn't seem related to the problem.

Comment: Is this a JS problem, a HTML problem, or a CSS problem? What did you try to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that your selectors is not "specific" enough.

So all you have to do is to add the relevant id to the `$("select")` like `$('#select_container select');`

**Demo**

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var selects = $('#select_container select');
  var values = '';
  selects.each(function() {
    values += '.' + $(this).val();
  });
  $(values).show();
  $('#select_container select').on('change', function(index, value) {
    if ($('#SelectOne').val() == 'Diesel') {
      $('#SelectTwo').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#SelectTwo').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    $('#results_container > div').hide();
    var values = '';
    selects.each(function() {
      values += '.' + $(this).val();
    });
    $(values).show();
  });
});

jQuery(function($) {
  var selects = $('#select_chart select');
  var values = '';
  selects.each(function() {
    values += '.' + $(this).val();
  });
  $(values).show();
  $('#select_chart select').on('change', function(index, value) {

    $('#results_chart > div').hide();
    var values = '';
    selects.each(function() {
      values += '.' + $(this).val();
    });
    $(values).show();
  });
});
```

```css
#results_container>div,
#results_chart>div {
  display: none;
}

.result {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.dif,
.difp {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: red;
}

.arrow {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  border: solid Red;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <div id="select_container">
    <select id="SelectOne">
      <option value="Fuel">Fuel</option>
      <option value="Diesel">Diesel</option>
    </select>

    <select id="SelectTwo">
      <option value="E-Plus-91">E-Plus 91</option>
      <option value="Special-95">Special 95</option>
      <option value="Super-98">Super 98</option>
    </select>

    <select id="SelectThree">
      <option value="Liter">Liter</option>
      <option value="Galon">Galon</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="results_container" class="result">
    <div class="Fuel E-Plus-91 Liter">3.22 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-0.62</span><span class="difp">-16.15%</span></div>
    <div class="Fuel Special-95 Liter">3.30 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-0.62</span><span class="difp">-15.82%</span></div>
    <div class="Fuel Super-98 Liter">3.41 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-0.62</span><span class="difp">-15.38%</span></div>
    <div class="Fuel E-Plus-91 Galon">12.24 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-2.36</span><span class="difp">-16.15%</span></div>
    <div class="Fuel Special-95 Galon">12.54 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-2.36</span><span class="difp">-15.82%</span></div>
    <div class="Fuel Super-98 Galon">12.96 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-2.36</span><span class="difp">-15.38%</span></div>
    <div class="Diesel Special-95 Super-98 E-Plus-91 Liter">3.87 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-0.27</span><span class="difp">-6.52%</span></div>
    <div class="Diesel Special-95 Super-98 E-Plus-91 Galon">14.71 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-1.03</span><span class="difp">-6.52%</span></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</center>

<center>
  <div id="select_chart">
    <select id="SelectOne1">
      <option value="cFuel">Fuel</option>
      <option value="cDiesel">Diesel</option>
    </select>

    <select id="SelectTwo1">
      <option value="cLiter">Liter</option>
      <option value="cGalon">Galon</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="results_chart" class="result">
    <div class="cFuel cLiter">[visualizer id="36" lazy="no" class=""]</div>
    <div class="cFuel cGalon">[visualizer id="39" lazy="no" class=""]</div>
    <div class="cDiesel cLiter">[visualizer id="43" lazy="no" class=""]</div>
    <div class="cDiesel cGalon">[visualizer id="48" lazy="no" class=""]</div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</center>
```

**Only one change request that will work for both.**

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('select').on('change', function(index, value) {
    var container = $(this).parent();
    if ($('#SelectOne',container).val() == 'Diesel') {
      $('#SelectTwo',container).prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#SelectTwo',container).prop('disabled', false);
    }
    container.next('.result').find('div').hide();
    var values = '';
    container.find("select").each(function() {
      values += '.' + $(this).val();
    });
    $(values).show();
  }).trigger("change");
});
```

```css
#results_container>div,
#results_chart>div {
  display: none;
}

.result {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.dif,
.difp {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: red;
}

.arrow {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  border: solid Red;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <div id="select_container">
    <select id="SelectOne">
      <option value="Fuel">Fuel</option>
      <option value="Diesel">Diesel</option>
    </select>

    <select id="SelectTwo">
      <option value="E-Plus-91">E-Plus 91</option>
      <option value="Special-95">Special 95</option>
      <option value="Super-98">Super 98</option>
    </select>

    <select id="SelectThree">
      <option value="Liter">Liter</option>
      <option value="Galon">Galon</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="results_container" class="result">
    <div class="Fuel E-Plus-91 Liter">3.22 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-0.62</span><span class="difp">-16.15%</span></div>
    <div class="Fuel Special-95 Liter">3.30 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-0.62</span><span class="difp">-15.82%</span></div>
    <div class="Fuel Super-98 Liter">3.41 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-0.62</span><span class="difp">-15.38%</span></div>
    <div class="Fuel E-Plus-91 Galon">12.24 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-2.36</span><span class="difp">-16.15%</span></div>
    <div class="Fuel Special-95 Galon">12.54 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-2.36</span><span class="difp">-15.82%</span></div>
    <div class="Fuel Super-98 Galon">12.96 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-2.36</span><span class="difp">-15.38%</span></div>
    <div class="Diesel Special-95 Super-98 E-Plus-91 Liter">3.87 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-0.27</span><span class="difp">-6.52%</span></div>
    <div class="Diesel Special-95 Super-98 E-Plus-91 Galon">14.71 AED <i class="arrow top"></i><span class="dif">-1.03</span><span class="difp">-6.52%</span></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</center>

<center>
  <div id="select_chart">
    <select id="SelectOne1">
      <option value="cFuel">Fuel</option>
      <option value="cDiesel">Diesel</option>
    </select>

    <select id="SelectTwo1">
      <option value="cLiter">Liter</option>
      <option value="cGalon">Galon</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="results_chart" class="result">
    <div class="cFuel cLiter">[visualizer id="36" lazy="no" class=""]</div>
    <div class="cFuel cGalon">[visualizer id="39" lazy="no" class=""]</div>
    <div class="cDiesel cLiter">[visualizer id="43" lazy="no" class=""]</div>
    <div class="cDiesel cGalon">[visualizer id="48" lazy="no" class=""]</div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: I used the first jQuery, it's work fine you can check the website oilprice.ae but it's slow 
I tried use the second one but it's not work fine

Comment: Don't seem slow to me. Also without seeing the second one i can't tell